# Python script mqtt reconnect after failure

Tags: python, bluetooth, mqtt

Hello I would need help on a python script that I use for the presence on my home automation it sometimes happens that mqtt is not available my script stops I would like it to retry a connection and restart the operation is  -it's possible ?

M'y script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import bluetooth
from time import sleep
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

phones = [
    {'name': 'person1', 'state': 'not home', 'mac': '<mac address>'}
    {'name': 'person2', 'state': 'not home', 'mac': '<mac address>'}
]

client = mqtt.Client("hass-client")
client.tls_set('/home/pi/certs/ca-certificates.crt')
client.username_pw_set('<username>', '<password>')
client.connect('<mqtt broker>', 8883)
client.loop_start()

while True:
    for phone in phones:
        key = "bluetooth/presence/" + phone['name']
        result = bluetooth.lookup_name(phone['mac'], timeout=3)
        if result != None:
            detected_state = 'home'
        else:
            detected_state = 'not home'

        if phone['state'] != detected_state:
            phone['state'] = detected_state
            client.publish(key, detected_state, retain=False)
    sleep(15)

client.disconnect()
```

Comment: Please also post the message you get when it stops (or that there's none). Also you may want note stay connected, but connect and disconnest for each message.

Comment: thank you for your answer, indeed I could make disconnect / reconnect but I do not find this solution very clean I would like to know if rather it is possible to do a check and if mqtt is not available that he waits and who tries this  connect make a loop, I have no log because I am currently at work I am looking for solutions

Comment: I quickly checked my own mqtt code - running in production at a radio station for 2 years and I do connect - publish - disconnect for every message. Which works fine and just crashes with an error that you can catch, I recommend that you set up a mqtt locally and test your code against that to see the different errors you need to catch. Also check that you're using Python3 and not old Python 2 from "#!/usr/bin/python"

Comment: Ok thank you for the idea so I will see to try what you said, indeed I will look at the python version also thank you for your help